# Disable file extension change prompts in macOS Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

When I change a file extension in Finder.app, I get prompted for confirmation.

How can I disable all of these? I never want to confirm the change.

[image: Are you sure you want to remove the extension ".png"?]

> Are you sure you want to remove the extension ".png"?
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.

[image: Are you sure you want to add the extension ".png" to the end of the name?]

> Are you sure you want to add the extension ".png" to the end of the name?
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.

[image: Are you sure you want to change the extension from ".png" to ".jpg"?]

> Are you sure you want to change the extension from ".png" to ".jpg"?
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Finder go to the "Finder" menu and select Preferences.
Click on the "Advanced" tab.
Either Check or Uncheck "Show warning before changing an extension" depending on the behavior you want.

```
Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Show warning before changing an extension
```

Note that it is not possible to change what the default action is (EG press Enter for [respectively] "Remote" , "Don't Add" , "Keep .png"). *That* is baked in to macOS as a default action. This is always going to be the action that will potentially **NOT** make a change that could cause a potential issue.